# ¿Porque esta matriz se muestra así?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

¿Sabríais decirme por que se muestra así la finalización del bucle for y no como quiero que lo haga (que es 2 3 4 8 9 7)? Por consola me sale esto:

```
2 8 
3 9 
4 7






public class Principal {

public static void main (String[] args) {

int [][] pubNotas = {2,3,4},{8,9,7};
for (int i=0; i<pubNotas.lenght; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j<pubNotas[i].length; j++) {
     System.out.print(" " + pubNotas[i][j] + " ");
}
System.out.println("");
...
```

Comment: La declaración de tu arreglo no es correcta, podrías copiarla tal y como la tienes cuando lo corres? pero lo que me imagino que pasa es que al tener dos ciclos anidados, por cada posición del primer arreglo se imprimen las posiciones del segundo arreglo (recordemos que un arreglo de dos dimensiones es solo un arreglo que contiene otro arreglo en cada una de sus posiciones)

Comment: Si quitas el ultimo System.out.println(""); debería de funcionar

Answer (score 2):

En principio al copiar tu código me daba error, no se si porque estoy usando una versión de Java anterior pero el array me daba problemas. Tras indicarlo como int `[][] pubNotas = {{2,3,4},{8,9,7}};` no daba problemas.

Después en tu for por cada vuelta del primero hacia un salto por culpa del `System.out.println("");`, si no querías un salto no entiendo la razón de ponerlo y si querías un espacio se te olvido indicarlo ya que esta vacío.

Puedes dejarlo como lo indicaron en otras respuestas como.

```
int [][] pubNotas = {{2,3,4},{8,9,7}};
    for (int i=0; i<pubNotas.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<pubNotas[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + pubNotas[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Tambien si le tienes cariño al print que has indicado con tan solo quitarle el **ln** del final se "arregla" pero la verdad estaria siendo un poco redundante.

Y por ultimo puedes indicarlo de esta manera.

```
for (int[] pubNota : pubNotas) {
            for (int i : pubNota) {
                System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
            }
        }
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

acá te dejo el codigo David, ojala te sirva y sea lo que querías

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int [][] pubNotas = {{2,3,4},{8,9,7}};
    for (int i=0; i<pubNotas.length; i++) {
        for (int j =0;  j<pubNotas[i].length;j++){
            System.out.print(" "+pubNotas[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución , considera agregar una explicación de lo que realiza ahora y como soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa por favor [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

public class Principal {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [][] pubNotas = {{2,3,4},{8,9,7}};

    String contenedor=" ";

    for(int i=0; i<pubNotas.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<pubNotas[i].length;j++){
            contenedor=contenedor+pubNotas[i][j]+" ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(contenedor);
}
```

}

Prueba con este código, consiste en agregar un contenedor dentro del ciclo anidado, luego al finalizar dicho ciclo imprimes el contenedor y tienes el resultado esperado. No olvides declarar la variable del contenedor de tipo String, iniciándola con un valor vacía (" ").